# SharePoint 2013 App Pools Crashing

Tags: sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2013

I have a newly configured SharePoint 2013 farm and my application pools continue to crash (stop).  I have these accounts added into Local Policies and Domain Policies for "Log on as Batch" and "Log on as Service".  The app pools in Windows Logs are coming back with errors about credentials being invalid.  I've never changed the app pool account passwords and in AD, they're set to never expire.  The accounts are not locked inside AD either.  It takes about 30 minutes of inactivity on the servers for an IISReset /noforce to bring them up.

These app pool crashes happen a couple times a day and appear to be desyncing with active directory somehow.  Changing the passwords to the unchanged password in IIS and PowerShell does not work because is claims the password is incorrect.  Have anyone come across this and have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are getting a false error? A common reason for application pool recycles is bad code in optimizations that doesn't clean up after itself.